# Flutter Testing. Asserting 'AppDrawer' exists in screen is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I need your help with one of the issues in my current project. I am very new to flutter (just 1 month of training) and I am trying to write some tests for my flutter code.

Most of my test code is working as expected, however I am stumped when I am working on testing my App Drawer.

I have a 'Screen A' which has  an 'App Drawer':

[image]

Below is the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            key: const ValueKey("appBar"),
            leading: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return IconButton(
                  key: const ValueKey('navigationMenu'),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                  },
                  tooltip: 'Open navigation menu',
                );
              },
            ),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
            iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text(
              'Home',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          drawer: AppDrawer(),
          body: Container(),
        );
      }
```

I want to test if my AppDrawer widget exists. Below is my code and it is not working:

```
    testWidgets('should open when clicked on hamburger menu', (WidgetTester tester) async {
          final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
          await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              body: AppScreen(),
            ),
          ));
          //Finder iconButton = find.byType(IconButton);
          //await tester.press(iconButton);
          scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          //Finder drawer = find.byType(Drawer);
          //ASSERT
          expect(find.byType(AppDrawer, skipOffStage: false), findsOneWidget);
    });
```

Below is the error

The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:

```
Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "AppDrawer">
   Which: means none were found but one was expected
```

I suspect that this issue might be due to drawer not visible by default. But I don't know how to fix this. I have been googling this issue for 2 days with no luck. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you created a scaffold key in the test environment and used that key to open the drawer but AppScreen also has a scaffold and that's the scaffold that holds the drawer.

You can find the icon by type or image and tap on it to open the drawer. Then await it to pump and settle and check if that is existing.

```
testWidgets('should open when clicked on hamburger menu', (WidgetTester tester) async {
          await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              body: AppScreen(),
            ),
          ));
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          Finder iconButton = find.byType(IconButton);
          await tester.tap(iconButton);
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          Finder drawer = find.byType(Drawer);
          expect(find.byType(AppDrawer, skipOffStage: false), findsOneWidget);
    });
```